# Problem with confirmation email for guest's order (Magento CE 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email, vat, guest-checkout, order-confirmation

I found two problems with the **email confirmation order** made by a guest with Magento CE 1.9.

1. I **receive** the confirmation email **only on one email** account, even if **I set it up on two** email account
2. **I don't see the VAT code** on the email, even if I've made the VAT field as **required**, also for guest, and I've put this data on the email template using this code → `{{var order.getData('customer_taxvat')}}`

The really strange thing is that **if it's a normal order**, the correct **email is sent to both of them** and I see the **VAT field**.

If it's a guest's order the email is sent to only one email and the VAT field is empty (or null, I don't know).

Someone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

For the 2. I think when you put an another variable in the template you have also put it into the order.php (app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/). In my case I put the customergroup code into the email. So I take this code into the order.php:

```
// Get customer group name for email template.
    public function getCustomerGroupName(){
    if ($groupId = $this->getCustomerGroupId()){
        $group = Mage::getModel ('customer/group')->load($groupId);
        if ($group->getId()){
            return $group->getCode();
        }
    }
    return '';
    }
```

maybe it could help you for your emailtemplate.
In the template I call it with:

```
{{var order.getCustomerGroupName()}}
```

For the 1. problem:
Have you set the right template in the order configuration? Maybe the variable is not caled there.

Comment: I respond in order:
1) Yes, I set the right template. There is a problem sending of the email, not only on the code of the template.
2) But why the same variable works if the order arrived from a registered user?